# Implementation of Oraclize API connector

Tags: solidity, oracles

Can someone explain to me how, where, and when is the
https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/master/connectors/oraclizeConnector.sol
deployed to ethereum blockchain ?
This is the implementation of doing the queries.
The user only imports the OraclizeAPI https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/master/oraclizeAPI_0.4.sol
in his own contract.
Where does reside the connector implementation? it's not specified in the OraclizeAPI.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do some detective work.

In the oraclizeAPI contract, there are these lines that connect to an OraclizeAddressResolver (OAR). If we look at the rest of the code, this OAR is queried for the current OraclizeConnector address, and then initialized.

The following lines state the active OARs on various networks the API will connect with:

https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/blob/master/oraclizeAPI_0.4.sol#L322-L327

            `OAR = OraclizeAddrResolverI(0x1d3B2638a7cC9f2CB3D298A3DA7a90B67E5506ed);`

So from that, it would appear giving `0x1d3B2638a7cC9f2CB3D298A3DA7a90B67E5506ed` address on mainnet a look would be worthwhile.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x1d3B2638a7cC9f2CB3D298A3DA7a90B67E5506ed#readContract

Reading the contract, as of this date it appears to have `0x3dbdc81a6edc94c720b0b88fb65dbd7e395fdcf6` address in its storage.

When we go to this address on etherscan, its verified code appears to point to it being `Oraclize Connector v1.2.0`

Comment: Doesn't that mean they can switch out the implementation under the hood at will, for example raising fees for deployed contracts that are already using their api?